# CSS Divs out of Place on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, cross-browser

Please look at these 2 pages on IE and on another Browser (like firefox)

http://www.zomghentai.com/kite-episode-1-sub/
and
http://www.zomghentai.com/stream/kite/

Notice the glitches on IE, a lot of things look out of place.

Can anyone tell me what CSS edits I should make to fix this ??

Edit :: I'm Using IE 8,  I posted screenshots in the comment below

Comment: What IE version are you using?

Comment: @Virendar , can you tell us what parts of broken , right now i don't have two monitors to compare side by side.

Comment: Seems fine in a side-by-side comparison between IE 8 and the latest version of Chrome. In other news, hentai? Really?

Comment: Screenshot : http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/4771/40466810.png and http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6475/31004131.png. @Code Gray: Please don't judge my website, I happen to like Hentai.

Comment: @darioo quite obviously, 6 & 7, as usual.. those awful pains in the a**

Comment: try installing Debugbar (http://www.debugbar.com/) & IETester (http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to see how websites look in previous versions of IE

Comment: I'm using IE version 8, as shown in my screenshot.

Comment: I only see the layout issue (as shown in your screenshot) if I turn compatibility view *on* in IE 8. Otherwise, it renders identically to Chrome and Firefox. I suspect there is a rendering issue on IE 6 and 7, but I think it's fixed with IE 8, as long as you're not running in compatibility mode, which brings all the bugs back so to speak. Also, it's not my personal opinions about hentai, but more of, am I sure I want to open this on a family/work computer...

Comment: Thanks Cody, I'll just leave a message telling people to disable IE using the IF IE code that Lucius mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your top menu is still set as a default unordered list, try floating left its LIs.
Also, IE < 8 's box model is different from the rest of the world's, so try to avoid using paddings & widths combined, or else, write a IE specific stylesheet and link it in the page head adding a code like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]><link href="style/iespecific.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
```